# How do I detect the 2 states of "Switch User" in Windows

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I'm wondering if anyone has had any experience with the API that gives you the possibility to detect the "Switch User" process under Windows XP.

I would like to know how I could detect that a user exits his account and when he re-enters it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want to look at the [`WM_WTSSESSION_CHANGE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383828%28VS.85%29.aspx) message.