# Detect enter/exit session under KDE/Gnome with FreePascal

Tags: session, gnome, kde-plasma, freepascal, switch-user

I'm asking this question after I got a very good answer to: [How do I detect the 2 states of “Switch User” in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/416313/how-do-i-detect-the-2-states-of-switch-user-in-windows)

My intention is to find out if the Switch User under KDE/Gnome has a similar API call I can monitor with FreePascal.

If not with FreePascal, at least the respective lib entry used in C/C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a dbus package is installed, and afaik I ran the examples end of last year.

See /packages/dbus/examples/busexample.pp for an example

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that monitoring DBUS messages you can catch messages about session enter and exit. Actually i don't know if FreePascal provide DBUS apis.

A dirty solution can be execution and parse */usr/bin/dbus-monitor* output.

Good luck